# HttpUrlConnection returns ResponseCode 404 but any browser can access the URL anytime

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, http-response-codes

I need to open a connection to an URL address and to read html with StringBuffer. However when i try to establish connection i get file not found exception 404. When i write this address in any browser on Windows or Android, address can be accessed anytime. I do not understand why this happens or is there any workaround.

```
URL meteo = new URL("http://meteo.bg/bg/osnOpasni");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) meteo.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html, */*");
        connection.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36");
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
```

If i use same code for any other URL - it works and the ResponseCode is 200. Is there anything i am missing???

Answer (score 0):

I try de URL on a browser with DevTools and the 404 error appears in the first place using the F12 Network analisis:

Seems like the URL is answering with a 404 error:

[image]

No error on your code the error is there in the website.

Comment: Yes, but i cannot force them to fix the error. Is there any workaround? How the browser displays the page?

Comment: There is a response message, what are you trying to do, even with the 404 error there is a response, so you can process it. We can discuss if this is a good idea.

Comment: i want to read the html code with BufferedReader and StringBuffer and read the html data of the page

Answer (score 0):

I was able to execute Http request to your URL and got the content without any problem. Here is my code:

```
public static void simpleHttpTest() {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    ResponseHolder<String> responseHolder;
    try {
        responseHolder = client.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/html")
            .sendHttpRequest("http://meteo.bg/bg/osnOpasni", HttpClient.HttpMethod.GET);
        System.out.println("Response received:\n" + responseHolder.getResponseContent());
    } catch (HttpClientCommunicationException hcce) {
        responseHolder = hcce.getResponseHolder();
        System.out.println("Error occurred:\n" + responseHolder.getResponseCode() + " " + responseHolder.getResponseMessage()
            + "\nResponse Headers: " + responseHolder.getResponseHeaders());
    }
}
```

Class `HttpClient` is a 3d party Http Client, and in general, I would suggest that you use some 3d party Http client and there are many available. This particular `HttpClient` comes with MgntUtils Open Source library written and maintained by me. This HTTP client is very simple to use, but it does not provide all the width of the functionality provided by other HTTP clients. Here is [Javadoc for HttpClient class](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/httpclient/HttpClient.html) that I used. The MgntUtils library can be obtained as [Maven artifact](https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.7.0.0) or from [GitHub](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (with source code and Javadoc). Also If you want to use well known Http clients I would suggest trying:

1. [Apache Http Client](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/)
2. [OK Http Client](https://square.github.io/okhttp/)

   BTW, the reason that you were getting 404 error may have been due to the site temporarily unavailable.

Comment: thank you very much mr.Gantman, there is an error on the page that is looking for some document resource which is not available on server. My idea was not to use a 3rd party client and i has left this for the end. However i have managed to get the html data with using the connection.getErrorStream() and i will now post the working code below

Comment: Regular Java SE has [its own HttpClient class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/package-summary.html#class-summary).

Comment: @VGR yes it does, so it doesn't invalidate other Http clients. The Http Client that I used is a special purpose Http client, that can be used as a general-purpose client as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a pretty simple solution of the problem with the error on html page which i am connecting to by using getErrorStream(). Here is the working code for this case:

```
URL meteo = new URL("http://meteo.bg/bg/osnOpasni");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) meteo.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
```

i hope this will help someone else, who has to deal with errors on html pages.